# Consumir repositório de entidades diretamente da camada de aplicação

Tags: c#, entity-framework, design-pattern, ddd

Tenho um cenário que preciso buscar uma lista de Funcionários ativos com Entity Framework e exibi-los na tela (preciso converter para DTOs antes de exibir - o que faço pela camada de Aplicação).

Para um cenário de DDD (***Domain-Driven Design***) existem as camadas de **Aplicação**, **Domínio** e **Infra**... Estou em dúvida neste escopo. Os **serviços de domínio** são criados quando a lógica tem importância para o domínio, certo ? Então, eu poderia buscar esta lista diretamente entre **Aplicação e Repositório**, desta forma, sem criar um serviço na camada de **Domínio** ? É claro, buscar uma lista de ativos seria apenas um filtro LINQ, não sei se posso considerar isso uma regra de negócio... Quem puder me esclarecer essa dúvida agradeço.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Em DDD, a camada de **Aplicação** sabe como consumir os objetos da camada de **Domínio** para atender as requisições da camada acima (**Interface**); e em DDD **repositório** é um tipo de objeto de domínio.

Ora, se a camada de Aplicação consome objetos de domínio e se repositório é um tipo de objeto de domínio, então não há necessidade de encapsular o repositório dentro de um serviço para que ele possa ser consumido pela camada de aplicação.

> Em DDD, a camada de Aplicação pode sim consumir repositórios diretamente, sem a necessidade de que estes repositórios sejam encapsulados em outro serviço.

É claro que se depois de obter as entidades ainda seja necessário executar qualquer lógica de negócio, esta lógica de negócio precisaria de fato estar em um **serviço** (que é um tipo de objeto de domínio em DDD) ou na própria **entidade**.

Observe ainda que o filtro que você vai executar sobre as entidades ao consumir o repositório diretamente da camada de aplicação precisa ser um filtro com uma API que fale a linguagem dos especialistas no negócio, já que em DDD todo o código da camada de domínio precisa falar esta linguagem.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta.